# Calling Boolean Array Methods of JAVA with Boolean ARRAY arguments in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I need to call some Java methods using C/C++ and then I need to use DPI in UVM or system verilog to call C methods.
I dont have access for JAVA files or JAVA classes. I have a .jar file in which my class is present of which methods I need to access. I am using path of that .jar file in

```
options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path= path of .jar file
```

I am able to find class using

```
clsH = env->FindClass("com/act/testdev/pa5/PA5");
```

But I am not able to get method ID. I know only method's name in java class which is a boolean method with boolean arguments

```
com.act.testdev.pa5.PA5.aes_encrypt(key_data, pt_data);
```

This method is used in some other language and here is the code of that  :

```
boolean[] aes_encrypt(boolean key_data[], boolean pt_data[]) 
{
    return com.act.testdev.pa5.PA5.aes_encrypt(key_data, pt_data);
}
```

Here is th code which I am trying to use to get the methodID.

```
if (clsH != NULL)
{
    //midMain       = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "<init>", "(ZZ)V");    
    midMain       = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "aes_encrypt", "(ZZ)V"); 
    printf("\n FOUND able to find the requested class midMain ==%x ==%x\n",midMain,clsH);       
}
else
{
    printf("\nUnable to find the requested class\n");       
}

if (midMain != NULL)
{
    //jstring StringArg = env->NewStringUTF("\nTestCall:Called from the C Program\n");
    printf("\nable to find the requested Method\n");        
    jbooleanArray BoolArg1 = env->NewBooleanArray(128);
    jbooleanArray BoolArg2 = env->NewBooleanArray(128);
    env->CallBooleanMethod(clsH,midMain,BoolArg1,BoolArg2);
    //env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clsH, midMain, NULL); //Calling the main method.
    //env->CallBooleanMethod(clsH, midMain, BoolArg); //Calling the main method.
}
```

Please help me on this how can I access this method in c/c++. there are some more methods also I need to call in same way once I am able to call this will try those later.
I dont have any Idea of JAVA I got this code online as a example of how to call java methods from c/c++.

Comment: Well, `Z` does not correspond to `boolean[]` [as you can see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html). You want `[Z`.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for correcting me. I tried it but result is same. midMain is NULL.
midMain       = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "aes_encrypt", "([Z[Z)V");

Comment: It does not return `V` (`void`). It returns `[Z` (`boolean[]`).

Comment: Hi Micheal,

I have corrected that also but Still midMain is NULL.
jmethodID midMain = NULL;
 midMain       = env->GetMethodID(clsH, "<aes_encrypt>", "([Z[Z)[Z");

Comment: Why did you add those angle brackets (`<>`)? They shouldn't be there.

Comment: That I have added by mistake by copy pasting <init> but I have tried without this result is same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe. `GetMethodID` works fine for me. The most likely problems are that the actual signature of the Java function isn't what you think it is, or that you haven't rebuilt the native library after making changes to the code.

Comment: Hi Micheal,

rebuilt the native library ? Actually I have created a CTest.cpp file in that I have just given path for .jar file which has java classes. and I am just using this command to execute the .cpp file
g++ -I/soft/uo/jdk1.8.0_11/include -I/soft/uo/jdk1.8.0_11/include/linux -L/soft/uo/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm CTest.cpp So I did not understand which library I need to rebuilt ?

Comment: clsH = env->FindClass("com/act/testdev/pa5/PA5");clsH1=env->FindClass("com/gate/sam/Samlet$BooleanArray");if (clsH1 != NULL){printf("\n FOUND able to find the requested class ==%x \n",clsH1);}else{printf("\nUnable to find the requested class\n");}if (clsH != NULL){midinit=env->GetMethodID(clsH, "<init>", "(III[I)V");midMain =env->GetMethodID(clsH, "aes_encrypt", "([Lcom/gate/sam/Samlet$BooleanArray;[Lcom/gate/sam/Samlet$BooleanArray;)[Lcom/gate/sam/Samlet$BooleanArray");printf("\n FOUND able to find the requested class midMain ==%x ==%x\n",midMain,clsH); }

Comment: Hi Micheal,
in this code able to find <init> method of PA5 class but still not able to find aes_encrypt method. I found that for Boolean Array there is another class. So I tried to link that calss in arguments and return type but still its not working. I am able to find boolean array class in cIsH1 handle.

Comment: The Java code you've shown uses `boolean[]`, not `Boolean[]`. So `[Z` is the proper signature.

Comment: Ok, I tried it by using ([Z[Z)[Z but I am not getting what is exactly issue there ?
is there any way I can understand .class file code if I want to understand it. as I dont have access to .java files.